Как взять максимально значение столбца в таблице в базе данных с redbean php
Надо найти максимальное значение score в таблице scores используя библиотеку именно redbeanphp. Не последнее, а максимальное!

select max(score) уже изобретен.

Как конкретно его использовать? Пример кинь

Документацию открой и почитай.

не могу найти там
